# XCode 8.0, Building for Store Submission, Errors

Tags: app-store, xcode8

Getting the following errors with XCODE 8.0.  This was working fine with Xcode 7.x as far as we can remember.

```
ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for xxx.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."
```

Does this mean that Apple is not smart enough not to include the simulator slice?  We have to provide an SDK that has the simulator and does not?

```
ERROR ITMS-90209: "Invalid Segment Alignment. The app binary at 'XXX' does not have proper segment alignment. Try rebuilding the app with the latest Xcode version."
```

But we are using the latest XCODE 8.0 version?  What gives here?

```
ERROR ITMS-90125: "The binary is invalid. The encryption info in the LC_ENCRYPTION_INFO load command is either missing or invalid, or the binary is already encrypted. This binary does not seem to have been built with Apple's linker."
```

Not sure what this is.  All Signing stuff is set correctly in all of the builds.  Again, this was working fine before.  We did use LIPO to make the universals.  So maybe stripping the universals would do it????

```
WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/mediumSDKSwift.app/Frameworks/VRSDK.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."
```

All PIE stuff was working find, no changes, etc.  All are set to NO for Position Dependent.  Have been doing some reading on this and some have solved by flipping bits?  hmmmm.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out we were providing a Universal Framework by mistake.  Once this was solved all of the errors were solved.

Comment: @Sana remove the problem folder from Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

Answer (score 3):

> ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for xxx.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."

This is a [known Apple bug](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6409498411401216).

Your other errors are resulting of manipulating an already signed product, so you have to code sign your product again after you sliced out the unsupported architectures.

---

Workaround:

The `Carthage` installer comes with a handy script, which I am using as an easy workaround.

1) Install [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases)

2) Add Build Phase Script

From [Carthage site:](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage)

> On your application targets’ “Build Phases” settings tab, click the “+” icon and choose “New Run Script Phase”. Create a Run Script in which you specify your shell (ex: bin/sh), add the following contents to the script area below the shell:

```
/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks
```

> and add the paths to the frameworks you want to use under “Input Files”, e.g.:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Box.framework
$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/Result.framework
...
```